# Forcing a Pod to be built as static library using a property

Tags: cocoapods

I wanted to know if there is any property that I can use to force a pod to be linked as static library. E.g.:

`pod 'RNPermissions', :link_as_static_library => true`

Tried lots of stuff checking `pod.build_as_static_library?` on post_install but it doesn't work when I check through.

As for now I'm doing this (CocoaPods 1.9.0):

```
$static_frameworks = ['RNPermissions', 'Permission-Camera', 'Permission-PhotoLibrary', 'Permission-Microphone']

pre_install do |installer|
installer.pod_targets.each do |pod|
 if $static_frameworks.include?(pod.name)
   puts "Overriding as static framework:#{pod.name}"
   def pod.build_type;
    Pod::BuildType.static_library
   end
  end
 end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

There is still no way to do this directly with stock CocoaPods (as of 1.12 / 2023).

Microsoft has a plugin that allows the linkage to be specified on a per-pod basis, instead of a per-target basis (https://github.com/microsoft/cocoapods-pod-linkage). There is a great discussion of how this works here: https://medium.com/microsoft-mobile-engineering/mixing-static-and-dynamic-linking-in-cocoapods-83b6d4252c59.

The method included in the question is still afaik the best / only way to modify linking of a single pod without a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can ink all pods as static libraries using:

```rb
use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
```